# How to add a link to <p:submenu>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

How can I add links to `<p:submenu />` for use with `<p:megaMenu>`?

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/pages/template/homeTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:megaMenu>
            <p:submenu label="Home" url="/" />
            <p:submenu label="Category" url="/cats">
                <p:column>
                    <p:submenu label="Category 1" url="/cats/cat1">
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 1" url="/cats/cat1/item1"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 2" url="/cats/cat1/item2"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 3" url="/cats/cat1/item3"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:megaMenu>  
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The `<p:submenu />` doen't have the `url` attribute, so it will be ignored, what can I do instead?

Comment: what's javascript and jquery got to do with it?

Comment: @Swarnajith primefaces includes jQuery in the page, so it's also possible to archive the result's using client side processing with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing this issue, I found lot's of people saying that it was not possible because primefaces doesn't support it, but there's a workaround if you don't mind using a bit of javascript:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/pages/template/homeTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:megaMenu id="megaMenu">
            <p:submenu label="Home" url="/" styleClass="homeLink" />
            <p:submenu label="Category" url="/cats" styleClass="catLink">
                <p:column>
                    <p:submenu label="Category 1" styleClass="cat1Link">
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 1" url="/cats/cat1/item1"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 2" url="/cats/cat1/item2"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Item 3" url="/cats/cat1/item3"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:column>
            </p:submenu>
        </p:megaMenu>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".homeLink a:first").attr('href', "#{request.contextPath}/");
            $(".catLink a:first").attr('href', "#{request.contextPath}/cats");
            $(".cat1Link").click(function(){
                window.location.href="#{request.contextPath}/cats/cat1";
            }).css('cursor','pointer');
        });
        </script>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

What I did here was:

1) I defined every `<p:submenu>` with an exclusive `styleClass`

2) If the `<p:submenu>` is on the first line, I changed the `<a>`'s `href` attribute to my link after the DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){
    $(".homeLink a:first").attr('href', "#{request.contextPath}/");
    $(".catLink a:first").attr('href', "#{request.contextPath}/cats");
});
```

3) If the `<p:submenu>` is part of a menu, I created an `onclick` attribute and customized the cursor to pointer since there's no `<a>` tag there.

```
$(".cat1Link").click(function(){
    window.location.href="#{request.contextPath}/cats/cat1";
}).css('cursor','pointer');
```

This resulted in the menu that I needed, and of course, will not work if javascript is disabled, but now the menu will work with javascript enabled browsers.

Comment: In my solution I had to remove onClick event listeners too; Can be done by using off, like $(".catLink a:first").off("click");